# Linked scene copy, unable to remove objects from rendering in that scene [Blender 2.90.1]

Tags: linked-data, scene

I am not sure if this is a bug or a "feature". When I create a linked copy and try to disable some objects from rendering, it disables them globally in every scene unless I make new scene a complete duplicate.

See the gif for what I mean..

[image: Susan won't go away]

Comment: Hello :). It's a feature. The Render switch (camera) and Viewport switch (screen) are linked attributes. The viewport visibility (eye) is not.

Comment: To render two versions of a scene, using the View Layers would be more suitable.

Comment: @JachymMichal hmm I am having the exact same issue with the view layers, I have done this many times before, but really struggling in 2.90.1

Comment: Hey :). My bad, I got confused, answer is up now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Collection checkbox.
It removes the whole Collection from the current View layer.

You can then use different View Layers, or different Scenes.

<sup>*Works with linked Scenes or different View Layers*</sup>
[image]